# Add a list into the front and back of a list of list

Tags: haskell

Example. I have a list, say [1,2,3], and I want to append it to a list of list so it looks like this.

```
[[5,5,5],[6,6,6]] -> [[1,2,3],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[1,2,3]]
```

How do I accomplish this? I can not do something like this

```
funk listOfList = [1,2,3] ++ listOfList ++ [1,2,3]
```

Or

```
funk [listOfList] = [[1,2,3], listOfList, [1,2,3]]
```

To be honest, I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `types` always makes everything clearer:

```
funk :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
funk listOfList = [[1,2,3]] ++ listOfList ++ [[1,2,3]]
```

If you use `(++)` for `[Int]` the result will be an `[Int]` too, so you actually want to use `(++)` for `[[Int]]` hence you need to use it with `[[1,2,3]]`

Comment: Right, I can not add a list of type [a] to another of type [[a]], but I can add together two lists of type [[a]]. Thank you!

Comment: @Salviati, consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. You are welcome

Comment: Absolutely. But there is a wait period of about 7 minutes. Hold on tight.